# ¿Existe realmente la Wiki de Comunidad?

Tags: soporte, wiki-de-comunidad

Sé que la Wiki Comunidad son todas las preguntas que no ganan reputación, pero eso no es una Wiki al estilo de Wikipedia.

¿Existe un enlace donde se pueden ver todas las preguntas wiki de manera categorizada?

¿Existe por lo menos algún filtro de búsqueda para ver todas las preguntas wiki?

Comment: Si te fijas en la ayuda de la búsqueda (dice `consejos de búsqueda avanzada`), veras que puedes poner `wiki:yes` o `wiki:no` para filtrar la busqueda, pero el objetivo de wiki comunitario no pasa por que no produce reputación, sino que, mantener esa info actualizada es un esfuerzo comunitario y no personal.

Comment: @rnd esa es una buena respuesta. Te recomiendo que la publiques

Comment: Lo que dijo @rnd **+** No existe una *Wiki al estilo de Wikipedia*, pero [hay planes para eventualmente agregar *Documentation*](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/697/127)

Comment: @rnd No había probado tocar click ahí, ni siquiera había notado que estaba eso. Eso me resuelve todo, yo iba buscando la pregunta que yo quería entre 40 páginas, ahora es más fácil.

Comment: En la respuesta agregué un enlace a una pregunta que permite ver los [meta-tag:faq] de manera categorizada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Se mencionó en un comentario, pero para que no quede como pregunta sin respuesta va una versión alterna.

## Resumen

> ¿Existe un enlace donde se pueden ver todas las preguntas wiki de manera categorizada?

No existe uno incluído en la interface de usuario pero existe [FAQ para sitios de Stack Exchange](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1378/faq-para-sitios-de-stack-exchange), el cual, como el título lo indica, es para los [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) (este mismo es un wiki de comunidad).

> ¿Existe por lo menos algún filtro de búsqueda para ver todas las preguntas wiki?

Sí. En la caja de búsqueda escribir `wiki:1` o `wiki:yes`. A continuación los enlaces:

- [Sitio principal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=wiki%3A1)
- [Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=wiki%3A1)

## Explicación

Al realizar una búsqueda, en el panel derecho se muestra el enlace "Consejos de búsqueda avanzada". Al hacer clic en este se muestra el recuadro siguiente:

[image]

Nótese que entre los ejemplos se muestra wiki:no, además, se incluye el enlace al [artículo de ayuda sobre búsqueda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)