# FAQ para sitios de Stack Exchange

Tags: soporte, faq

> TRABAJO EN PROGRESO (Más detalles en la sala de chat [Acerca del índice del FAQ de la Comunidad](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53106/faq-de-la-comunidad-trabajo-en-progreso)

## FAQ de la Comunidad

**Para los sitios en la red Stack Exchange 2.0**

Para ver una lista de palabras y frases de uso común en inglés, ver el [Glosario](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/40353).

Para una guía oficial de Stack Exchange en inglés, visite el [Centro de ayuda](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help).

---

### Modelo y modos de Stack Exchange

Actualmente Stack Overflow en español es el único sitio 100% en español en [se], pero los siguientes FAQ bien podrían servir como base para otros sitios que se agreguen en un futuro.

#### Conceptos

- [Vota pronto, vota con frecuencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2209/)
- [¿Qué es una publicación "Wiki de comunidad"?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317/)
- [¿Qué es el voto serial y cómo me afecta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/663/)
- [¿Qué es una 'reversión'?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/816/)
- [¿Qué es una respuesta aceptable?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/958/)
- [¿Qué es una publicación bloqueada?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1994/227)

#### Preguntar

- [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/)
- [¿Cómo consigo respuestas rápidamente?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1445/)
- [¿Qué puede causar que una pregunta sea relanzada?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1650/)
- [¿Qué es el Problema XY?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3360/15301)

#### Edición

- [¿Conoces los magic-links para los comentarios? Aprende a usarlos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1058/)
- [¿Es posible re-dimensionar una imagen en una publicación?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1137/)
- [¿Qué es el resaltado de sintaxis? ¿Cómo funciona?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1463/)
- [¿Qué combinaciones de teclas hay disponibles en el sitio?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2178/)

#### Privilegios

- [¿Por qué necesito 50 puntos de reputación para comentar? ¿Qué alternativa tengo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/586/)

#### Código de Conducta

- [¿Cómo dar las gracias a los usuarios que responden a mis preguntas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1624/)

#### Moderación

- [¿Cuándo debería votar?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1075/)
- [¿Qué es un reporte en disputa?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1944/)
- [¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones? ¿Por qué podría eliminarse una publicación y qué implica? ¿Cuál es el criterio para eliminar?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1033/)
- [¿Qué es una elección? ¿Cómo se elige y cómo funciona?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2256/)
- [¿Cómo uso correctamente el reporte "No es una respuesta"?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2973/)
- [¿Qué son las auditorías y cómo funcionan?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3727/)

#### Varios

- [Lista de páginas no enlazadas en los sitios de Stack Exchange](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1157/)
- [¿Cómo funcionan las @respuestas en los comentarios?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1357/)
- [¿Cómo crear o solicitar una nueva etiqueta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/440/)
- [He creado una etiqueta accidentalmente, ¿cómo puedo borrarla?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3115/)
- [¿Cómo invitar a un chat privado a alguien?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1698/)
- [¿Quiénes forman el Community Team? ¿Qué hacen?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1670/)

### Stack Overflow en español

FAQ sobre temas muy específicos relativos a la temática del sitio o bien a la relación con [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com)

- [¿Cómo sugerir una mejor traducción de la UI?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/73/)
- [Si tengo algo nuevo qué preguntar ¿debo preguntarlo en ambos sitios?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/76/)

### Enlaces Externos

Enlaces tomados de la sección External Links de  [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)

- [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)
- [Help Vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)
- [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)
- [Writing the Perfect Question by Jon Skeet](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
- [How to Ask Questions the Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)
- [What have you tried?](//mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)
- [Ten Simple Rules for Getting Help from Online Scientific Communities](http://www.ploscompbiol.org/article/info:doi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pcbi.1002202)

---

### ¿Tu pregunta no forma parte de la FAQ?

Primero mira las preguntas etiquetadas [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) para ver si hay una pregunta no en este índice que podría tener la respuesta que buscas. Si todavía no puedes encontrar una respuesta, consulta las siguientes instrucciones para proponer que una pregunta sea incluída en las preguntas frecuentes.

#### ¿Cómo puede una pregunta añadirse a esta lista?

- Redacta la pregunta de forma lisa y llana en el cuerpo de la pregunta.
  La respuesta va en una respuesta. Puedes elegir alguna de entre los no traducidas en [¿Sabes inglés, quieres aportar a la comunidad de SOes y no sabes cómo? ¡Traduce un FAQ!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1381/83).
- **Volver** a este índice. Pega este al final de la pregunta:

  `[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)`
- Marcar como [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) y [soporte](/questions/tagged/soporte).  Cuando una publicación parece que ha alcanzado un estado maduro, un moderador le agregará [faq](/questions/tagged/faq).
- Repórtala para que un moderador la marque como **wiki de la comunidad**.  Cualquier publicación que sea una Preguntas frecuentes que aún no esté marcada como wiki de la comunidad debe ser marcada como tal.
- Después de que la publicación tiene añadida la etiqueta [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), añadir un enlace en el [índice](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/) anterior.