# ¿Qué recurso tengo si pienso que un moderador ha abusado de sus privilegios?

Tags: soporte, faq, moderación

> Adaptación de [What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused his/her privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/)  (pregunta)

Una o más de las siguientes cosas me han ocurrido en un sitio de Stack Exchange:

- Mi(s) publicación(ones) has sido borradas o bloqueadas erróneamente por un moderador.
- Un moderador ha publicado un comentario erróneo en una de mis publicaciones
- Fui suspendido, pero no he hecho nada malo
- Hice una meta-pregunta, pero la pregunta fue cerrada y/o eliminada.
- Un moderador me ha desacreditado en público.
- ...

Pienso que un moderador ha abusado de su poder y estoy indefenso ante esta situación.

¿Qué recurso tengo? **¿Qué puedo hacer cuando siento que un moderador ha abusado de su poder y ha sido repetidamente injusto en su trato conmigo?**

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Answer (score 4):

> Adaptación de [What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused his/her privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/what-recourse-do-i-have-if-i-believe-a-moderator-has-abused-his-her-privileges/28869#28869) (respuesta)

Si tienes un disputa con un moderador diamantado tus opciones son:

- Envía un mensaje al equipo de Stack Exchange a través del enlace "contacto" al pie de cualquier página con tu queja y enlaces a las preguntas/respuestas.
- Reporta para atención de moderador y solicita que un segundo moderador mire el caso.

Para el registro, aquí están los niveles de moderación (del superior al inferior):

- Empleados de Stack Exchange ([equipo de comunidad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-team-and-what-do-they-do) (en inglés), desarrolladores)
- [Moderadores diamantados](http://stackexchange.com/about/moderators) (en inglés) - Elegidos por la comunidad o designados como moderadores "pro tempore" para sitios beta.
- Usuarios regulares con [privilegios basados en reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges?tab=moderation)

Algunos consejos no solicitados:

*A menudo es mejor intentar solucionar las cosas al menor nivel posible.* Si tienes un problema con un moderador, es más rápido para ti ponerte en contacto con cualquiera de los "moderadores diamantados" en tu sitio, pues ellos tienen la mayor experiencia en tu sitio específico y pueden ver otras acciones que has llevado a cabo que dan contexto al incidente en cuestión. Algunas veces querrás ir a un nivel superior (o incluso al nivel más alto) con una queja o solicitud, pero toma en cuenta que el receptor se preguntará la razón por la cual esta persona con una queja no pudo resolverla con el equipo de moderadores que hemos asignado para hacer eso mismo.

Comment: Me resulta curioso que se hable de _moderadores diamantados_ (_diamond moderator_ en inglés), como si hubiera moderadores sin diamante.

Comment: @fedorqui - será porque todos somos moderadores con ciertos privilegios (según reputación)..quizás sea eso del diamante para distinguier.. o no se.. :)

Comment: @aldanux querrán hacer un [_be moderator, my friend_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQ683zlrUSI) :D

Comment: @fedorqui: El título de la siguiente pregunta y la pregunta marcada como original me parece explican la cuestión: [“Diamond Moderator” vs “Moderator”, are they the same?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128565/diamond-moderator-vs-moderator-are-they-the-same?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Yo opino que en SOes es "Ajo y Agua"

Comment: @toledano: ¿que tal si "bautizamos" como "Ajo y Agua" a la sala de chat general  de SOes? XD