# ¿Qué puede causar que una pregunta sea relanzada?

Tags: soporte, faq, relanzado-de-preguntas, preguntas

> Esta es una traducción de [What can cause a question to be bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-a-question-to-be-bumped)

¿Qué puede causar que una pregunta sea "relanzada" (*bumped*) a la primera página de la pestaña de Activas en un sitio de Stack Exchange?

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Esta es una traducción de la respuesta aceptada en [What can cause a question to be bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579/209901)
>   Corrige todo aquello que veas que no es correcto o necesite mejora.

Los siguientes motivos causan que una pregunta sea relanzada:

- Se le añade una nueva respuesta.
- Edición o reetiquetado de la pregunta, o edición de una de sus respuestas.<sup>[*]</sup> <sup>[**]</sup>
- Se le ofrece una recompensa (por parte de cualquier usuario)
- [Reapertura efectiva](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129185/when-a-question-gets-reopened-it-should-get-a-bump/129198#129198) (si la pregunta estaba cerrada).
- El usuario Comunidad relanzará preguntas que no tuvieron actividad durante 30 días, no puntuadas negativamente, y que [tengan al menos una respuesta con una puntuación de 0 y ninguna con puntuación positiva](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/155074).

  - Las preguntas [se eligen aleatoriamente de entre las preguntas más vistas y que han estado inactivas por más de 30 días](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99690).
  - Si una cuestión es relanzada, [no podrá ser relanzada de nuevo hasta que pasen 120 días](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1374/was-there-a-change-to-the-community-bot-that-stops-it-from-bumping-questions/1375#1375), *a menos* que reciba actividad desde que se relanzó por última vez.
  - El número de preguntas no respondidas por hora depende del sitio: 4 por hora en Stack Overflow, 1 por hora en Meta y 2 por hora en Super User y Server Fault. Un nuevo sitio tiene un valor de [1 por hora](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511) por defecto.
  - Algunos sitios [tienen límites de cuántas preguntas pueden relanzarse](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7542448#7542448). Una vez este límite se alcanza, no se relanzan más preguntas hasta que una o más de las relanzadas desaparece de la página de inicio.

Las siguientes acciones *no* causan el relanzado de una pregunta:

- Eliminación o recuperación de una pregunta o una respuesta.
- Votos positivos o negativos a la pregunta, a las respuestas o a los comentarios.
- Votos de cierre o reapertura en la pregunta.
- Reportes (ofensivo/spam/moderador).
- Creación o eliminación de comentarios.
- [Ediciones pendientes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80186).
- Aceptación de una respuesta.
- Protección o desprotección de la pregunta.

---

<sup>[*]</sup> Esto es cierto para ediciones que generan una revisión en el historial de la publicación. Las ediciones en una publicación realizados dentro de los 5 minutos siguientes a su creación o a una revisión que genere edición se juntan a los cambios de la edición anterior, por lo que no provocan un relanzado de la publicación.

<sup>[**]</sup> Las preguntas con un puntaje suficientemente negativo *no* serán relanzadas cuando ellas o sus respuestas sean editadas. El umbral de "suficientemente negativo" está definido en -4 para Stack Overflow y nuevo sitios, y -8 en Meta Stack Overflow (a [25 de agosto de 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62261/are-edited-questions-no-longer-bumped-to-the-front-page/62262#62262) -- véase el comentario de Grace Note).

Comment: @Mariano gracias por poner orden en mi traducción, claramente estás deseando entrar en [spanish.se] :P

Comment: jajaja. Seré obsesivo con el lenguaje, pero si no entré con [esta pregunta](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20113) que pide a gritos una buena respuesta con fuentes sólidas, te veo peleando una dura batalla para convencerme... Hablando en serio, ya hay confianza, no hace falta agradecer. Sé que hubieses hecho lo mismo.