# Dado que se prohibe duplicar preguntas ¿Cómo se convierte una pregunta en frecuente?

Tags: soporte

Siempre he tenido por norma revisar los FAQ de los sitios a los que acudo para documentarme antes de formular mis preguntas.
He encontrado en SO (en las secciones que he visitado) que hay una pestaña de preguntas frecuentes y la he recorrido sin detenerme a pensar en su significado. Pero, ante la frecuencia con que (al consultar los tags que me interesan y las preguntas recientes) he encontrado la anotación: **Esta pregunta ha sido marcada como duplicada por n1, n2, ... acompañada de un enlace** Me asaltó una duda ¿Se incluye una pregunta en el FAQ porque alguien con mucha experticia la considera importante? o, ¿porque su enlace ha sido ofrecido muchas veces a quienes sin saberlo preguntan en duplicado?
¿Cómo reacciona SOes ante las preguntas duplicadas? ¿Simplemente se marcan y eventualmente se retiran, o afectan el peso de la solución que se ofrece a cambio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Va una respuesta rápida...

Las preguntas que aparecen en la pestaña Frecuentes son preguntas han sido usadas para marcar otras como duplicados de estas.

En las etiquetas podrían incluirse "preguntas frecuentes" seleccionadas por los editores del wiki de etiqueta.

Cabe mencionar que en Meta tenemos la etiqueta [faq](/questions/tagged/faq).

Relacionado

- [FAQ para sitios de Stack Exchange](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/65)
- [¿Por qúé algunas preguntas son marcadas comod duplicadas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: De acuerdo con lo que acabo de leer (en por qué se marcan como duplicadas), ¡mi pregunta es duplicada!

Comment: @quevedo : No se pueden marcar preguntas duplicadas de artículos de ayuda :)